# How can I format the day of the week as a single letter?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

To format my ticks to display an abbreviated day of the week, I can use:

`.tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%a")) // Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat Sun`

How can I format the day of the week as a single letter?

`.tickFormat(d3.timeFormat()) // M T W T F S S`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no [time format](https://github.com/d3/d3-time-format/blob/master/README.md#timeFormat) in D3 library to display just the first letter of the day.

However, the task here is very simple. First, let's see a *regular* axis, and then show a couple of solutions.

This is the regular axis:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg")
var scale = d3.scaleTime()
  .range([20, 480])
  .domain([new Date(), new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() + 7)]);

var axis = d3.axisBottom(scale)
  .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%a"))
  .ticks(d3.timeDay);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0,50)")
  .call(axis)
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg width="500"></svg>
```

**Solution #1**: Using `substring`:

```
.tickFormat(function(d) {
    return d3.timeFormat("%a")(d).substring(0, 1)
})
```

Here is the demo:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg")
var scale = d3.scaleTime()
  .range([20, 480])
  .domain([new Date(), new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() + 7)]);

var axis = d3.axisBottom(scale)
  .tickFormat(function(d) {
    return d3.timeFormat("%a")(d).substring(0, 1)
  })
  .ticks(d3.timeDay);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0,50)")
  .call(axis)
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg width="500"></svg>
```

**Solution #2:** using `slice`:

```
.tickFormat(function(d) {
    return d3.timeFormat("%a")(d).slice(0, 1)
})
```

Here is the demo:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg")
var scale = d3.scaleTime()
  .range([20, 480])
  .domain([new Date(), new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() + 7)]);

var axis = d3.axisBottom(scale)
  .tickFormat(function(d) {
    return d3.timeFormat("%a")(d).slice(0, 1)
  })
  .ticks(d3.timeDay);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0,50)")
  .call(axis)
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg width="500"></svg>
```

**Solution #3:** using `charAt`:

```
.tickFormat(function(d) {
    return d3.timeFormat("%a")(d).charAt(0)
})
```

Here is the demo:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg")
var scale = d3.scaleTime()
  .range([20, 480])
  .domain([new Date(), new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() + 7)]);

var axis = d3.axisBottom(scale)
  .tickFormat(function(d) {
    return d3.timeFormat("%a")(d).charAt(0)
  })
  .ticks(d3.timeDay);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0,50)")
  .call(axis)
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg width="500"></svg>
```

**Solution #4:** using the index:

```
.tickFormat(function(d) {
    return d3.timeFormat("%a")(d)[0]
})
```

Here is the demo:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg")
var scale = d3.scaleTime()
  .range([20, 480])
  .domain([new Date(), new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() + 7)]);

var axis = d3.axisBottom(scale)
  .tickFormat(function(d) {
    return d3.timeFormat("%a")(d)[0]
  })
  .ticks(d3.timeDay);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0,50)")
  .call(axis)
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg width="500"></svg>
```

**Solution #5:** using a regex (just because):

```
.tickFormat(function(d) {
    return d3.timeFormat("%a")(d).match('^.{0,1}')
})
```

Here is the demo:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg")
var scale = d3.scaleTime()
  .range([20, 480])
  .domain([new Date(), new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() + 7)]);

var axis = d3.axisBottom(scale)
  .tickFormat(function(d) {
    return d3.timeFormat("%a")(d).match('^.{0,1}')
  })
  .ticks(d3.timeDay);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0,50)")
  .call(axis)
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg width="500"></svg>
```